# C++ Design and polymorphism

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have a generic question on C++ class design. For example I have a need for a packet generator. So given a type of packet I have to generate the packet of that type. So I have a base packet generator class.

Approach 1:

```
class BasePacketGenerator {
public:
    virtual Packet* generatePacket (int type); // implements the generic case
                                               // hence not pure virtual
protected:
    //
    // Common functionality for all types
    // 
   virtual void massagePacket (Packet& pkt); // called by generatePacket
                                           // but needs special handling for 
                                           // some types
   virtual void calculateCheckSum(Packet& pkt); // called by generate packet
   ...
};
```

Derived classes to handle each type:

```
class Type1PacketGenerator : public BasePacketGenerator {
public:
    // Dont have to override any base class implementationa
protected:
    void calculateCheckSum(Packet& pkt) override;
};

class Type2PacketGenerator : public BasePacketGenerator {
public:
    Packet* generatePacket(int type) override;
};
```

Here for Type1 generator, we are using polymorphism. But the base-class calls, the derived class functionality polymorphically. I wonder if this is a good Idiom? Or there should be a intermediator class

Approach 2:

```
class TypeHandler {

    virtual Packet* setupPacket();
    virtual void calculateCheckSum(Packet& pkt);
    virtual void setupFields (Packet& pkt);
}

class PacketGenerator {
public:

    TypeHandler *handler_; // lets say this is setup based on the type

    Packet* generatorPacket(int type)
    {
       auto packet = handler_->setupPacket();
       handler_->massagePacket();
       handler_->calculateCheckSum(*packet);
       return packet;
    }
}
```

Is there any advantage with going with one approach or the other?

Approach1 is more flexible as it doesn't have to follow the same way of doing things. Eg: if Type2Generator doesn't need a checksum, it doesn't even have to call the calculateCheckSum() or if it needs some additional functionality, we don't have to add it to all Type generators.

But Approach 2 is more readable as all types do the things same way.

Comment: Looks like a factory pattern?

Comment: I believe your second example is touching on the topic of policy based design - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design. It goes well with templates.

Comment: The answer to your question very depends on different factors. Class Design should take into account many aspects of the domain and the problem. For example, why you cannot implement the "simplest" polymorphism design? [Example Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98159aabcce2c8ea). A `packet` interface and different implementations for each type.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: This is similar to my Approach 2, except that it used a pure interface class. I will try to see if I can make an interface class and sort of abstract out common functionality to another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern design sensibilities tend to favor a very aggressive separation of concerns. As such, this leads to preferring base classes that are nothing but pure virtual function declarations.

Each class is responsible for 1 thing.

As such, your second approach is considered much preferable. The main reason (and the only one you really need) being: it makes it much easier to write proper unit tests.

**Edit:** mind you, it still looks a bit clunky, but this is more a matter for [The codereview stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), where you could get detailed feedback on your structure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. regarding `base classes that are nothing but pure virtual function declarations`. This could be achieved if I move all common functionality to another class and each type handler simply refers to it I guess.